# There is no sound in Fluxbox

Tags: sound, configuration, fluxbox

In both Gnome and Unity sound works pretty great. But, when I switch to Fluxbox, voila, no sound! How do I fix this?

Also, I saw the keyboard shortcuts in the ./fluxbox/keys folder, and they simply seem to do nothing.

They are configured like this:

> Control 1 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 1+
>
> Control 2 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 1-
>
> Control 0 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 toggle

What do I do?

Comment: are you sure the sound isn't muted?

Comment: Is PulseAudio running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had ti power up the `gnome-sound-applet` in `.fluxbox/startup`, and it appears the sound was muted there. It works now.

Answer (score 3):

check for muted sound, using `alsamixer`

m toogles the mute. MM represents a muted device, OO a non-muted one

Answer (score 0):

Go to Applications > System > Administration > Gnome Control Center and click the sound icon. Check to see if anything is muted.

If this doesn't work, try pavucontrol

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful project to launch a sound applet on fluxbox bar:

Try: https://github.com/Maato/volumeicon